# Как изменить мета тег Title в админке WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как изменить заголовок именно в админке WordPress? Нужно убрать именно слово "WordPress", которое добавляется после заголовка на каждой странице в админке. Может, как-то через functions.php?

[image: Всегда после заголовка добавляется "- WordPress"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте следующий код в functions.php

```
function my_admin_title( $admin_title, $title ) {
    return str_replace( ' &#8212; WordPress', '', $admin_title );
}

add_filter( 'admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!